# Fullcalendar jquery not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fullcalendar

I am working on Fullcalendar selectable jquery. I need to use it in wordpress. I have created a template file and call the calendar div in template file and include css files "fullcalendar.css" and "fullcalendar.print.css" in header and "moment.min.js" and "fullcalendar.min.js" in footer. It is only showing calendar without any css effect and not working selectable event. Files are included correctly and not showing any javascript error. I am using this fullcalendar script. I have tried to deactivate all plugins.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2016-08-05',
        theme: true,
        selectable: true, 
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:'); alert(title);
            var eventData;
            if (title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                };

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
            } 

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2016-08-09'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2016-08-07',
                end: '2016-08-15'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2016-06-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2016-06-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2016-06-11',
                end: '2016-06-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2016-06-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2016-06-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2016-06-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2016-06-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Happy Hour',
                start: '2016-06-12T17:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dinner',
                start: '2016-06-12T20:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2016-06-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2016-06-28'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid you need to set up a demo on the web or at jsfiddle.

Comment: i have tried it on localhost it is working and in wordpress main root it is working but when i am trying to use it on ant template file in theme then it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

My issue has been resolved.I was adding  "fullcalendar.print.css" after "fullcalendar.min.css". When i commented "print.css" file then it started working fine.